# SQL Arrays are returned as strings in PHP

Tags: postgresql, php, array

I have a column with type `Array`, I need to get all the elements in the array, I tried:

`SELECT managers_ids::INTEGER[] FROM teams WHERE id = 14`

the result is  `'{8,9,10}'`. How can I iterate on the results when it's returned as a string?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm unsure what you want. Show so you have an array `{8,9,14}` you want to check if 14 exists and when you find out it doesn't you want it to return nothing? Can you write an example?

Comment: The problem that when i try to handle it in php, php see it as string not as array so i could not collect the ids from it

Comment: What is the data type of the `manager_ids` column?

Comment: The type is `INTEGER[]`

Comment: @MohammadAL-Raoosh can you pick an answer or tell us what you're looking for?

Comment: If the type of `managers_ids` is `INTEGER[]`, then the cast in your `SELECT` is redundant noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using PHP with SQL Arrays

I would highly suggest **never** using PHP. However, when you can't avoid it you may find [this post useful on reading PostgreSQL arrays as PHP Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3068683/124486). People have been [complaining about this for 15 years now](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php#18749). PHP doesn't migrate SQL arrays into native PHP array structures.

### Getting around the problem with JSON

The new method of working around PHP's long-standing inadequacies is to use [`JSON` to move the array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-json.html).

```
SELECT array_to_json(pg_array_result) AS new_name FROM tbl1;
$array = json_decode($returned_field);
```

Attribution: shamefully stolen from [michaelbn's answer on StackExchange.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670706/124486).

### Getting around the problem with `unnest`

You have another option to use unnest and return a result set which PHP can handle.

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AS t(x);
 x 
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on official documentation. You can select from an array in the same way you normally access a multidimensional data object.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Specifically review section 8.14.3. Accessing Arrays

Keep in mind in Postgres, arrays begin at 1  not 0. In your example, the following query:

`SELECT managers_ids[2] FROM teams WHERE id = 14`

Would yield:

`{9}`

You could then cast this to an integer.

Comment: Thanks, but we need to read all the array, we actually did so, but we could not iterate through the result, as we got a string, while we expected to have an array as a result..

Comment: `managers_ids[2]` already returns `integer`, so `9`, not `{9}`. No cast needed. Also, is this an answer to the *question*?